# Squid Integration With Active Directory Best Practise

Tags: ldap, kerberos, ntlm, squid, centos6

There are different ways to integrate squid in AD Domain. 
But what is Best practice. use **ntlm, ldap, kerbereos**. have any idea?

Is there caomplete guide how to do it with centos 6 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kerberos, plain and simple....

Comment: Thank you. It seams kerberos is good thing.